# Trace Statement Execution in Jupyter Notebooks?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, trace

I am currently writing some Python code in a Jupyter notebook and I wonder if there is any possibility to track the execution of statements directly in Jupyter? I know there is this module called "trace": https://docs.python.org/3/library/trace.html#trace.Trace.results But it seems to me that with "trace" it is only possible to show the flow of execution in the console or to export it to a new file. However, I would like to display it directly in Jupyter Notebooks. Is this possible - with or without the mentioned module - and if yes how?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

For something along the lines of debugging code, you may be interested in the cell magic `%%debug`, discussed [here](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2018/10/17/jupyter-notebook-debugging/) to open a debugger in the notebook and use `pdb` commands. Or [PixieDebugger](https://medium.com/codait/the-visual-python-debugger-for-jupyter-notebooks-youve-always-wanted-761713babc62) if you need something fancier.

You may also be interested in the variable inspector extension for JupyterLab. There is (old) an animated example of using it [here](https://github.com/lckr/jupyterlab-variableInspector#jupyterlab_variableinspector). You can easily try it out by clicking on `launch binder` badge [there](https://github.com/lckr/jupyterlab-variableInspector) and starting a notebook. Then right-click in the open notebook and select `Open Variable Inspector` from the list. The animation will show you how to drag the tabs to arrange them side by side on your screen. Now as you run code, you'll see the variables updated.